# Attract large amounts of vermin

Tags: dnd-3.5e

### I want some way to attract large amounts of vermin on command.

I was thinking of using the Paladin spell **Telepathic Aura** along with the feat **Mark of Vermin** from Dragonmarked *(p.143)* that makes me treat vermin like they have an int of 2 but making a wand with that costs like 44k so i was wondering if there's anyone who knows of a better way?

Comment: Just leave your food scraps on the ground, you'll have plenty of vermin in a day or so :-)

Comment: Yeah sorry should have added on command but that's a good starting idea for the build thanks :)

Comment: Would a wand of Summon Swarm work?

Comment: Not really the build is going Verminlord utilizing the hivemind lvl 10 ability so i think it needs to be legit vermins not summoned.
Good suggestion though

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think any effect will do *exactly* what you want: cause a swarm of vermin to appear then stay forever so that you can play with it. But the 3rd-level Sor/Wiz spell *Halaster's fetch I* [conj] (*City of Splendors: Waterdeep* 153) *et al.* calls instead of summons creatures from the *summon monster* spell lists, so a DM may allow the researching of a similar original spell (*DMG* 198).

That is, the hard part is not *attracting* the vermin but *making them stay*. A variety of effects can bring forth swarms of vermin: the 2nd-level Sor/Wiz spell [*summon swarm*](http://www.systemreferencedocuments.org/resources/systems/pennpaper/dnd35/soveliorsage/spellsS.html#summon-swarm) [conj] (*PH* 289) and its ilk are the most obvious ways, but creatures summoned that way disappear when the spells end. I guess the 6th-level Sor/Wiz spell [*planar blinding*](http://www.systemreferencedocuments.org/resources/systems/pennpaper/dnd35/soveliorsage/spellsPtoR.html#planar-binding) [conj] (*PH* 261) and the 8th-level [*greater*](http://www.systemreferencedocuments.org/resources/systems/pennpaper/dnd35/soveliorsage/spellsPtoR.html#greater-planar-binding) (*ibid.*) can bring forth, respectively, a rapture locust swarm or a bloodfiend locust swarm (*Fiend Folio* 170), swarms of vermin with the extraplanar subtype, and, afterward, you can try to strike a bargain with that swarm. Um. Good luck?

## Get a swarm of vermin as an improved familiar

Likely the easiest way to always have a swarm of vermin nearby is to make the swarm a familiar. A creature that can summon a familiar can take the feat [Improved Familiar](http://www.systemreferencedocuments.org/resources/systems/pennpaper/dnd35/soveliorsage/featsGen.html#improved-familiar) (*DMG* 200) to gain a swarm familiar (*Dragon* #329 Class Acts: Wizard column “Swarm Familiars”); in such a fashion, a [spider swarm](http://www.systemreferencedocuments.org/resources/systems/pennpaper/dnd35/soveliorsage/monstersS.html#spider-swarm) (*MM* 239-40) is available at caster level 3 to neutral master. (I am almost certain there's an option for a druid to take as an animal companion a swarm but can only find feats and class features that allow an individual vermin as an animal companion.)

### Further, instead or also, control swarms of vermin you encounter

The Cliffhangers Adventures Web article ["Approaching Swarm: Episode Five: Hive Mind"](http://archive.wizards.com/dnd/article.asp?x=dnd/ch/ch20020708a) includes the *3e* feats Vermin Control and Vermin Defiance which were not updated by the *3.5* revision and, therefore, game legal but subject to minor modifications by the DM (*DMG* 4). As the *3.5* revision eliminates the spell *animal friendship*, this DM recommends changing the spell to the unique new spell *charm vermin* (*a la* the spell *animal friendship* becoming, essentially, the spell *charm animal*).

The pair of feats is available to a level 3 druid or, if early access to the feats is a must, any human level 1 mystic ranger (*Dragon* #336 105).

A creature with these feats can command vermin in much the same way [an evil cleric can command undead](http://www.systemreferencedocuments.org/resources/systems/pennpaper/dnd35/soveliorsage/specialAttacks.html#table-turning-undead). Further, *Libris Mortis* on Undead Swarms and Turning says

> Because undead swarms are made up of many weak undead creatures, they are more vulnerable to turning than normal undead. For all purposes related to a turning check or turning damage, treat the undead swarm as having only one-half (50%) of its normal Hit Dice. Add any turn resistance only after halving the swarm’s HD. (82)

With this in mind, it seems reasonable to apply such rules equally to swarms of vermin when a creature with the feats Vermin Control and Vermin Defiance attempts to turn or rebuke an *actual* swarm of vermin.